# How do I add an installed application to startup?

Tags: boot, pi-4

I have an application installed from a .deb file, how can I add this to startup so that it opens once my raspberry pi has booted? I can't seem to make the examples I found work and they all look like they're for running scripts, not an installed application.

Comment: More details please. What is the name of the app, is it a command-line app or does it have a GUI, which examples - what have you tried?

Comment: To start an application on boot up it is necessary to know how it is started on the command line. Please start the application manual from the command line, then [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/118892/edit) your question and add the command to it.